# Integrating Pentaho with GWT

Tags: gwt, charts, reporting, pentaho

We have a web application which is build using GWT and Spring. We are planning to integrate Pentaho as a reporting and charting tool in the application. What would be a good way to do the integration?

Any insight, links experiences would be helpful.

Comment: did you find any good way to do the integration? I am trying to integrate Pentaho and ExtJS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own UI, you should use [olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/).